# Find the objects that a line intersects in three.js

Tags: javascript, math, three.js

Currently, I'm working on a three.js project where I should select two boxes from a board and draw a straight line connecting them, then I must highlight all the boxes that the line intersects. My big question now is how to to find which boxes the line intersects?

Any help would be appreciated (piece of code, links, material suggestion, math formulas)

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing sounds like you're looking for a [Raycast](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster).

You set up your ray (it's position and direction vector), and then use `intersectObjects` on the objects to get an array of the boxes the ray intersects.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I thought that Raycast was only for showing where the mouse is pointing to. So apparently I can set a Raycast to point everything an object intersects? This way I'd have to raycasts one for the mouse and one for the line?

Comment: Can I set a raycast to a fixed position instead of the mouse? If so I could set its position as the same of the line. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: Yes, you can use 2 raycasters.  For this one, just use .set() instead of .setFromCamera()
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster.set
Set the origin to one of the points, set the direction to the vector difference of the two points, and discard any intersections that are further along the ray than the 2nd point.

Comment: Diarmid, Thanks for the clarification, I added a second raycaster, named raycaster2, however, I'm getting an empty array. I updated the code on my post. Any idea of how  I can fix that?

Comment: When I console.log(raycaster2) I can see that the origin and direction are correct. I really don't know why I keep getting an empty array on intersects2

Comment: I just figured out that the line was with z position as 1, so it wasn't touching the grid. However even when I change the Z position to 0 the intersects2 array gives me an empty array

Comment: @LucasBrodersen the Bresenham algorithm (that you reference in your answer) is generally used to convert a line to raster graphics (ie, a bitmap).  I believe Ivan's suggestion is on the mark, but you'll likely need to introduce a proximity factor when using the Raycast function, in particular the `params` object which includes thresholds defining the precision of the raycaster when intersecting objects.

Comment: An alternative to using a proximity factor would be to give your squares some actual depth (i.e. make them boxes rather than squares), and set the z-coordinate for your raycaster in the middle.  Pretty sure that with that approach you will get all the intersections that you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

What I really needed in this case was bresenhams line algorithm, with this I can track all different points that the line crosses.

Found at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bresenhams-line-generation-algorithm/

Thanks Ivan and Diarmid, I know my code was a big mess and you tried to help me despite that.